# How to use Hosted Feature Layer in ArcGIS Pro from ArcGIS Online Content without editing original Layer file

Tags: arcgis-pro, layers, arcgis-online, storage, hosted-feature-layer

I am accessing a certain hosted feature layer from ArcGIS Online Content storage that has both a point and polyline layer. I want to open the file in ArcGIS Pro and make an editable copy that will NOT cause changes to the original file stored in our ArcGIS Online Content. When I make a copy of the layer in ArcGIS Pro and proceed to edit, the edits affect the original file in our ArcGIS Online Content.

In short I want to:

- Use ArcGIS Online Content to store the layer shapefile in its original format
- Access that content through ArcGIS Pro through "Add Data"
- Utilize those data to make edits on the point layer
- Maintain original layer file in ArcGIS Online Content but also save map from ArcGIS Pro with an edited  and manipulated layer derived from the original file.

Still learning GIS, self-taught.

Comment: I would simply make a copy of the layer you want to edit in ArcGIS Online then access that through ArcPro.

Comment: Just to be clear... are you wanting to edit the feature data (geometry/shape and/or attributes, add/change/delete features), OR are you wanting to edit the layer (symbology, labels, definition query, etc)?